# Testing web server through linux terminal

Tags: python, http, testing, web

I was just curious, how can I write a python test code so that I can test the GET/POST methods? 
I am unable to figure out a way so that running the server and testing these methods can be done at the same time. Can someone help, thanks

```
from os import curdir
from os.path import join as pjoin

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class StoreHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    store_path = pjoin(curdir, 'store.json')

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            with open(self.store_path) as fh:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(fh.read().encode())

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/store.json':
            length = self.headers['content-length']
            data = self.rfile.read(int(length))

            with open(self.store_path, 'w') as fh:
                fh.write(data.decode())

            self.send_response(200)


server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), StoreHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Put your testing code in a different script and run it after the webserver is started with the first script

Comment: Im not sure about the syntax and how to connect the the server. I have the server up and running but I just cant figure out how to connect and interact with it. could anyone write a basic test code for me?

Comment: I posted an answer; but so you know for in the future, people are more likely to help if you show you put effort into finding a solution before asking on StackOverflow. Something like "Here's my problem: ... Here's what I tried: ..."

This was also easily Google-able, you should always start there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/store.json")
print(r.status_code)
```

this will give back `200` as specified in your code